# Pass json object to mvc4 controller - array passed as Nothing

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have searched and found quite a few results on this but none of them seemed to work. I can see there are values in params.list array (as shown below by console.log) but in the controller ZoneDataList is "Nothing" although vm.farmId, vm.cropPlanId and vm.taskId have data in the Controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:
Javascript:

```
var zonedataArray = [];
    var zoneInfo = {};
    var params = { farmId: localStorage.FarmId, cropPlanId: selectedCrpPlanId, taskId: taskId, list: [] };

    for (i = 0; i < viewModel.nutZoneRows().length; i++) {
      zoneInfo = { "Rate": viewModel.nutZoneRows()[i].Rate(), "TotalAmount": viewModel.nutZoneRows()[i].TotalAmount() };
      zonedataArray.push(zoneInfo);
      params.list.push(zoneInfo);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < params.list.length; i++) {
      console.log("params.list[i].Rate: " + params.list[i].Rate);
    }//has correct values

    $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: '@Url.Action("SaveNutritionTask", "CropPlans")',
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify(params),
      traditional: true,
      success: function (result) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
      } //error

    }); //ajax
  }; //self.SaveCropPlan
```

Controller method:

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function SaveNutritionTask(vm As CropPlanModel.CompleteZoneData) As JsonResult

End Function
```

Model:

```
Public Class CompleteZoneData
  Public Property farmId As Guid
  Public Property cropPlanId As Guid
  Public Property taskId As Guid
  Public Property ZoneDataList As List(Of ZoneData)
End Class

Public Class ZoneData
  Public Property Rate As String
  Public Property TotalAmount As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. list in params in the javascript code should be renamed to ZoneDataList to match the Class name.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to use a model binding attribute for binding json (this is a c# implementation that you might need to translate to VB)

```
   public class FromJsonAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
   {
         private readonly static JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
         {
     return new JsonModelBinder();
  }

  private class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
  {
     public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     {
       var stringified = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[bindingContext.ModelName];
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringified))
            return null;
       return serializer.Deserialize(stringified, bindingContext.ModelType);
      }
 }
```

}

and the modify your controller function like

```
       <HttpPost()>
       Public Function SaveNutritionTask([FromJson]vm As CropPlanModel.CompleteZoneData) As JsonResult

       End Function
```